# How to scrape and transfer only specific data to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For a project, I'm trying to scrape the macronutrients from this [website](https://www.jumbo.com/producten/jumbo-scharrelkip-filet-800g-515026BAK), this is the table below called 'Voedingswaarden' I'm trying to scrape and I only want the information marked with red. The problem I found is that there is no TH in the table, the TH is also a TD with the same class name called 'column'. How can I separate those 2 TD's so I have 1 for the column and one for the value for a Pandas DataFrame?

Thanks for any help you can provide.
[image].

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] - On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in addition to @Jurakin how decomposes elements from the tree, you could also select only elements you need with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), so tree will not be effected in that way. [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) will extract the pairs texts you can build your `DataFrame` on.

### EDIT

As you only like to scrape the red marked parts, you could go with the same methode, but have to use [`pandas.set_index(0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`pandas.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to transform and make the first column to headers.

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.jumbo.com/producten/jumbo-scharrelkip-filet-800g-515026BAK',headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'}).text)

pd.DataFrame(
    (e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('table tr:not(:has(th,td.sub-label,td[colspan]))')),
).set_index(0).T
```

##### Output

|  | Energie | Vetten | Koolhydraten | Vezels | Eiwitten | Zout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kJ 450/kcal 106 | 0.8 g | 0.0 g | 0.0 g | 24.7 g | 0.14 g |

---

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.jumbo.com/producten/jumbo-scharrelkip-filet-800g-515026BAK',headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'}).text)

pd.DataFrame(
    (e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('table tr:not(:has(th,td.sub-label,td[colspan]))')),
    columns = soup.select_one('table tr').stripped_strings
)
```

##### Output

|  | Voedingswaarden | per 100g |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Energie | kJ 450/kcal 106 |
| 1 | Vetten | 0.8 g |
| 2 | Koolhydraten | 0.0 g |
| 3 | Vezels | 0.0 g |
| 4 | Eiwitten | 24.7 g |
| 5 | Zout | 0.14 g |

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those `tr` that have a child `td` that has a `sub-label` class or contains a `col-span` attribute, then pass it to `pd.read_html` to create a data frame.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.jumbo.com/producten/jumbo-scharrelkip-filet-800g-515026BAK"

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5026.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1254.0"

# get page source code
page = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent})
page.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# find table
table = soup.find("table")

# check existence of the table
assert table, "no table found"

print(table)

# select garbage
# - td containing sub-label in class
# - td with colspan attribute
garbage = table.find_all("td", class_="sub-label") \
        + table.find_all("td", colspan=True)
for item in garbage:
    # remove item with its parent tr
    item.parent.decompose()

# load html into dataframe
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

print(df)
```

This is the table printed from code:

```
<table aria-label="Table containing info" class="jum-table striped" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
    <thead data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
        <tr class="header-row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <th class="header-column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="" id="Voedingswaarden"> Voedingswaarden </th>
            <th class="header-column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="" id="per 100g"> per 100g </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Energie</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">kJ 450/kcal 106</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Vetten</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.8 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            # contains sub-label class
            <td class="column sub-label" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">-waarvan verzadigde vetzuren</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.4 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Koolhydraten</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.0 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            # contains sub-label class
            <td class="column sub-label" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">-waarvan suikers</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.0 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Vezels</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.0 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Eiwitten</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">24.7 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">Zout</td>
            <td class="column" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">0.14 g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">
            # contains colspan attribute
            <td class="column" colspan="2" data-v-038af5f8="" data-v-e2cf3b44="">*Het zoutgehalte bestaat uit van nature voorkomend natrium.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output dataframe:

```
  Voedingswaarden         per 100g
0         Energie  kJ 450/kcal 106
1          Vetten            0.8 g
2    Koolhydraten            0.0 g
3          Vezels            0.0 g
4        Eiwitten           24.7 g
5            Zout           0.14 g
```